# How to include dataLayer function in angular (click) method

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-analytics

I want to include dataLater.push with the click handler in angular

```
(click)="someFunc(); this.dataLayer.push({'event': 'Some event'})"
```

This works but not what I want:

`onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'Some event'});"`

I also tried using a function referenced in my ts file:

```
  dataLayer: any[];
 someFunc(){
    this.dataLayer.push({'event': 'Some event'});
  }
```

The function is not recognized, although when using javascript onClick method it works, how can I use it in angular click handler.

Comment: you do the push inside someFunc() function

Comment: Tried that as well, didnt work

Comment: were you getting same not recognised issue there as well?

Comment: just remove 'this' from this.dataLayer.push({'event': 'Some event'})

Answer (score 0):

You can add the push in the function that is being called on the click event.

```
<div class="clickable" (click)="someFunc()">Click here</div>

someFunc() {
    this.dataLayer.push({'event': 'Some event'});
}
```

The way you are using the angular click event is correct.